# Retrieving date time between a period

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a list of records, in my case are matches, and each match have a "date_time" that the game starts, i need to get all the matches that shows 1 hour before it starts and stays on the page after 5 hours. But i believe im not doing right, is not working right

code:

```
$liveMatches = SoccerMatch::where('date_time','>',Carbon::now()->subHour())
            ->where('date_time', '<',Carbon::now()->addHours(5))
            ->where('status',1)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `->whereBetween()` method

Try the following:

```
$liveMatches = SoccerMatch::whereBetween('date_time',[Carbon::now()->subHours(5)->subSeconds(5),Carbon::now()->addHour()->addSeconds(5)])
            ->where('status',1)
            ->get();
```

Check [Query Builder docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses) and let me know if it worked

Comment: hello, thanks for the response, is not working completelly, because imagine this situation, the current date time is 2017-08-03 11:00:00 and i have a match that started at "2017-08-03 09:15:00", the record is not showing, it only shows if it the match is 10:15:00, for example if a match is at "2017-08-03 09:15:00", it should already show on the records at "2017-08-03 08:15:00" and stays after 5 hours of that time ("2017-08-03 13:15:00".

Comment: Oh I missunderstood, try my updated answer. We were wrong, we are looking for matches which date_time is inside last five hours or date_time is inside now and next hour

Comment: No, is not working, because if the time now is 12:00 and the match is at 13:00, is not showing it one hour before.

Comment: Yes, cause forget to add some seconds , try my updated answer again